# How to use an adjacency matrix to determine which rows to 'pass' to a function in r?

Tags: r, loops, spatial

New to R, and I have a long-ish question:

I have a shapefile/map, and I'm aiming to calculate a certain index for every polygon in that map, based on attributes of that polygon and each polygon that neighbors it.

I have an adjacency matrix -- which I think is the same as a "1st-order queen contiguity weights matrix", although I'm not sure -- that describes which polygons border which other polygons, e.g.,

```
POLYID A B C D E  
    A  0 0 1 0 1  
    B  0 0 1 0 0    
    C  1 1 0 1 0     
    D  0 0 1 0 1     
    E  1 0 0 1 0
```

The above indicates, for instance, that polygons 'C' and 'E' adjoin polygon 'A'; polygon 'B' adjoins only polygon 'C', etc.

The attribute table I have has one polygon per row:

```
POLYID TOT L10K 10_15K 15_20K ...  
     A 500   24     30     77 ...
```

---

Where TOT, L10K, etc. are the variables I use to calculate an index.

There are 525 polygons/rows in my data, so I'd like to use the adjacency matrix to determine which rows' attributes to incorporate into the calculation of the index of interest.  For now, I can calculate the index when I subset the rows that correspond to one 'bundle' of neighboring polygons, and then use a loop (if it's of interest, I'm calculating the Centile Gap Index, a measure of local income segregation). E.g., subsetting the 'neighborhood' of the Detroit City Schools:

```
Detroit <- UNSD00[c(142,150,164,221,226,236,295,327,157,177,178,364,233,373,418,424,449,451,487),]
```

Then record the marginal column proportions and a running total:

```
catprops <- vector()
for(i in 4:19)
{
  catprops[(i-3)]<-sum(Detroit[,i])/sum(Detroit[,3])
}
catprops <- as.data.frame(catprops)
catprops[,2]<-cumsum(catprops[,1])
```

Columns 4:19 are the necessary ones in the attribute table.

Then I use the following code to calculate the index -- note that the loop has "i in 1:19" because the Detroit subset has 19 polygons.

```
cgidistsum <- 0
for(i in 1:19)
{  
   pranks <- vector()
   for(j in 4:19)
    {
      if (Detroit[i,j]==0)
        pranks <- append(pranks,0)
      else if (j == 4)
      pranks <- append(pranks,seq(0,catprops[1,2],by=catprops[1,2]/Detroit[i,j]))
      else 
        pranks <- append(pranks,seq(catprops[j-4,2],catprops[j-3,2],by=catprops[j-3,1]/Detroit[i,j]))
    }
  distpranks <- vector()
  distpranks<-abs(pranks-median(pranks))
  cgidistsum <- cgidistsum + sum(distpranks)
  }
cgi <- (.25-(cgidistsum/sum(Detroit[,3])))/.25
```

My apologies if I've provided more information than is necessary. I would really like to exploit the adjacency matrix in order to calculate the CGI for each 'bundle' of these rows.

If you happen to know how I could started with this, that would be great.

and my apologies for any novice mistakes, I'm new to R!

EDIT:

I've since figured out how to approach this, but for the sake of problem clarity and in response to one question asked in the comments, let me say that a polygon's neighborhood is the union of itself and every polygon it is adjacent to.  In the example I gave above, for polygon 'A', that would be the union of polygon's 'A', 'C', and 'E'

Comment: Thanks @DWin for your helpful formatting edits.  I will take note of them for the future.

Comment: a lot of information is confusing. Can you explain the index calculation in pseudo code? I mean in English, distinguishing the case the polygon is adjacent or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, although it doesn't appear to be as elegant as @agstudy 's:

```
for(k in 1:nrow(adjacency00))
 {
  positions <- grep(1,adjacency00[k,])-1
  nghbrd <- UNSD00[c(positions,k),]
```

etc., thereby creating a frame of adjacent polygons on which to conduct subsequent calculations

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear how you do you want to exploit the adjency matrix.

One idea is to formulate your problem as a graph one. The igraph is suitable to manipulate adjacent edges and vertex.

here my idea:

```
# I read the adjency matrix
POLYID.adjency <- read.table(text ='A B C D E  
A  0 0 1 0 1  
B  0 0 1 0 0    
C  1 1 0 1 0     
D  0 0 1 0 1     
E  1 0 0 1 0',header = TRUE)
# I create the graph
require(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(adjmatrix=POLYID.adjency)
V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
```

As option you can plot it :

```
 plot(g)
```

[image]

Now I use the attributes matrix , to create an attribute for each edge ( since each Row is an edge)

# I create a dummy attributes matrix

```
POLYID.attributes <- read.table(text =' TOT L10K 10_15K 15_20K 
A 500   24     30     77
B 400   25     30     87
C 300   26     30     97
D 200   27     30     57
E 100   28     30     47',header = TRUE)

# I set the attributes
for(x in colnames(POLYID.attributes)){
   g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, name = x,
                         value=  POLYID.attributes[,x])

  }
```

Now all the problem info is in the graph.

```
str(g)
IGRAPH DN-- 5 10 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), label (v/c), TOT (v/n), L10K (v/n),
        X10_15K (v/n), X15_20K (v/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
 [1] A->C A->E B->C C->A C->B C->D D->C D->E E->A E->D
```

Now I can get the information of each node using igraph options, e.g:

e. get the  L10K attributes of the polygon adjacent to B

```
V(g)[get.adjlist(g,'out')$B]$L10K
[1] 26
```

Here I compute the sum of TOT of all the polygons adjacent to the plyogon A:

```
 sum(V(g)[get.adjlist(g,'out')$A]$TOT)
  400
```

Comment: Wow @agstudy.  That is very, very cool.  And explicitly spatial.  Unfortunately, I figured out my own, kludgy way to do this (explained in a separate answer).  But I will definitely keep this one in mind!)

Comment: @dubhousing why not use mine? It is difficult ? or no time to use it?

Comment: my apologies, but i figured mine out 1st, came back here to report, and saw yours.  mine works well enough, and I am indeed very short on time, which means I probably wouldn't be able to dwell on your approach sufficiently to understand it.  Thanks again, though.

Comment: @dubhousing no problem. I am just curious to see the behaviour of the graph method in real case.